# Using Watir with Chrome browser to find element on just opened web page

Tags: watir-webdriver

I try to find button on just opened page without sleep command.

HTML:

```
 <span id="create-user-button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default
 ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
 <span class="ui-button-text">Create‌·User</span>
 </span>
```

Initialization of my element:

```
  span(:create_user_button, :id => "create-user-button") 

  def open_user_creation_dialog
  sleep 1
  self.create_user_button_element.when_visible.click
          end
```

When i use piece of code without sleep for Chrome browser, my page is closed and i can't find defined button. There isn't such problem for FF.
I try to use a lot of variants to fix it, like  :

```
  self.create_user_button_element.when_visible(2).click

  self.create_user_button_element.when_present(2).click
```

Solution was found :

My page doesn't use Ajax, but there is very big table with users on my page, it takes a lot of time to download.
So i am waiting for download big table and after that i find very well my element.
My problem was solved.

```
   div(:total_users_number, :id => "users-table_info")
   def open_user_creation_dialog 
   self.wait_until(10, "No users displayed") do 
   self.total_users_number_element.when_visible.text != ""
   end 
   self.create_user_button_element.when_visible.click 
   end
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to provide a little more information before I'd be able to help you. What is the error you're getting? What is the HTML of the element you're trying to click? What is the actual Watir code that defines that element? Also, all your "def" lines above are mal-formed Ruby, so it's hard to really understand what your methods actually do in your code.

Comment: @Abe Heward Ok.I will try to give you more information.I will revise my question.

Comment: If you use a really high timeout - eg 2 minutes, does it work? I am wondering if Chrome is just too slow or there is a different issue.

Comment: @Justin Ko Chrome is too fast, 2 minutes doesn't work either.Defined window is closed in Chrome without sleep.

Comment: Is your page Ajax-heavy? I know that Cheezy's PageObject gem has a #wait_for_ajax method available.

Comment: @Abe Heward My page doesn't use Ajax, but there is very big table with users on my page, it takes a lot of time to download.
So i am waiting for download big table and after that i find very well my element.
My problem was solved.

Comment: @Abe Heward. Yes, you can accept my answer and i will add some information on this about delay:
         `div(:total_users_number, :id => "users-table_info")
          self.wait_until(10, "No users displayed") do
          self.total_users_number_element.when_visible.text != ""
          end`

Comment: I can't accept your answer. You asked the question. If you have the answer then you need to answer your question and accept your answer.

Comment: @Abe Heward. Ok.I posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have page with a very loadful content, namely list of users, so i should wait for element with big content. I do it, this way :

```
       div(:total_users_number, :id => "users-table_info")
       self.wait_until(10, "No users displayed") do
       self.total_users_number_element.when_visible.text != ""
       end
```

When this element loaded, i can find my sought element
           self.create_user_button_element.when_visible.click